# Doesn't a cross-post require moderator intervention?

Tags: support, flagging, flag

I flagged https://serverfault.com/q/514541/152253 with a custom message:

> This question has been asked on SO as well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17032121/1544337 and seems to get more response there.

As far as I know, you shouldn't cross-post. I found the question here on SF less valuable and best removed, since the question on SO got more response and a bounty from the OP.

However, the flag was declined:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Doesn't a cross-post require moderator attention?

What are the guidelines for cross-posts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I declined the flag, precisely because it is on-topic here.

Typically if a post is cross-posted to multiple sites, it should be closed on the sites on which it is *not* on-topic. I'm a bit surprised that it wasn't closed on SO; that's not a topic I usually expect to see left open there. (But the presence of the bounty prevents people from voting to close it.)

There's more, in this particular case; I asked the OP to clarify his question, but he never came back to do so. If *he* wanted it closed, for whatever reason, I'd be much more inclined to do so. And if he doesn't do so soon, I might close it anyway.

Comment: Since this was a odd-case you probably should have written a custom decline message. Otherwise kudos for taking the time to figure out what was going on.

Answer (score 2):

It is a cross-post, but it's topical here. We could flag the SO post as belongs on us for just as good reason (even though it's bountied over there).

We do discourage cross-posting, preferring to pick a site and merge. But... not always.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Duplicate flagging works across sites.

I think the appropriate action is to mark it Off-Topic if you feel that it should be removed.